# Bigquery pricing for Temporary storage

Tags: google-bigquery

**Background**

I am loading data to BQ.Each time i load data to BQ using **schema autodetect** option for which BQ creates a table with schema.Then i download the autogenerated schema and delete the created table.
I need to this task ,few times on a shedule basis.

I have read in documentation that:
for 100 MB for a month it costs some amount and i have read that loading data is free.

**Query**

Will this storage cost me any amount?

Apart from storage ,will i be charged for this activity.

Need your suggestions on these.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such term as temporary storage. As you say you will pay the storage for the time that you keep it. There is a cost if you do streaming insert, but if you do a load job from a file there is no cost for the bandwidth, but you pay the storage price as normal. Also you don't pay for cached queries.

The following table summarizes BigQuery pricing. BigQuery's quota policy applies for these operations.

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Action              | Cost                    | Notes                                                           |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Storage             | $0.02 per GB, per month | See Storage pricing.                                            |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Long Term Storage   | $0.01 per GB, per month | See Long term storage pricing.                                  |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Streaming Inserts   | $0.01 per 200 MB        | See Storage pricing.                                            |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Queries             | $5 per TB               | First 1 TB per month is free, subject to query pricing details. |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Loading data        | Free                    | See Loading data into BigQuery.                                 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Copying data        | Free                    | See Copying an existing table.                                  |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Exporting data      | Free                    | See Exporting data from BigQuery.                               |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Metadata operations | Free                    | List, get, patch, update and delete calls.                      |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

All this is explained better on the official page:   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

You can check out your current usage on this page:
https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/unbilledinvoice

And there is a pricing calculator here:
https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

**Update**

Storage pricing is prorated per MB, per second. For example, if you store:

- 100 MB for half a month, you pay $0.001 (a tenth of a cent)
- 500 GB for half a month, you pay $5
- 1 TB for a full month, you pay $20

Comment: ok,got that,they have monthly plans ,but i want to store data for hardly a minute,so will i be applicable to the monthly plans.In that case,it seems  as a disadvantage!

Comment: hold on, if you store for 1 minute you will be billed to that, price is proactive, so it won't count like it's been there for a month, just for 60 seconds. You can even set expire times on table, and then automatically cleanups

Comment: the only relevant here info I can add is that minimum price is for 10MB and all sizes are rounded to next 10MB during the calculations